# How to call JavaScript function in GridView Command Field?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have return one Javascript function which asks the confirm message to the user. 
The JavaScript functions is

```
    function ConfirmOnDelete() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete?"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

and GridView is like below:

```
    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

Here I want to call the JavaScript function when user clicking the Delete in the GridView Command Field.
How to call this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep using your `CommandField`, you could do this programmatically using your GridView's `OnRowDataBound` event.

Specify the event handler for the RowDataBound event in your `GridView` declaration:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"....
```

Then in your event handler (code-behind) find your button (here I'm assuming `ImageButton`, though this depends on your `ButtonType` property in your `CommandField`) and add JavaScript to its `OnClientClick` property.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[cell].Controls[ctrl]).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"; // add any JS you want here
    }
}
```

In the above example, *cell* refers to the column index of your `CommandField` and *ctrl* refers to the control index (Delete button) within the cell you're referencing.

Answer (score 3):

You better avoid ask the confirmation for deletion on the server side, capture the user final decision using javascript then go to the server side to execute your logic. CommandField will not be the best solution here.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DeleteConfirm() {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer from excluded customer list ?")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" ">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_RemoveFromlist" runat="server" Text="Delete"
                        CommandName="Delete" OnCommand="Delete_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID").ToString()' OnClientClick='return DeleteConfirm()'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code:

```
protected void Remove_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Implement your Delete Logic
}
```

Comment: not sure what you plan to achieve by not closing the code block here - CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID").ToString()'

Answer (score 2):

for cancel button have command name as "cancel" and for delete button "delete" , check

```
if(e.CommandName == "delete")
 {
   //script to delete();
 }
else if(e.commandName == "cancel")
 {
   //close with some script;
 }
```

To call javascript function in codebehind,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function","loadPopupBox();", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you have to specify `OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?');"` but that doesn't work with **CommandField** better use **TemplateField**,  this explains better http://davesquared.net/2007/10/confirm-delete-for-gridview.html

Comment: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandField' does not have a public property named 'OnClientClick'. This would have to be added programmatically to either the cell or the delete button in the cell.

Comment: yes i tried, but it shows the errors as "CommandField does not have a public property named OnClientClick".

Answer (score 1):

you can use **OnClientclick** event of button to call the function.For example

```
<asp:button id="btndelete" runat="server" Text="delete" Onclientclick="if(!ConfirmOnDelete())return false;"/>
```

Comment: OP is referring to <asp:CommandField> which doesn't have an OnClientClick property.

Answer (score 0):

use start up script

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "ConfirmOnDelete", "ConfirmOnDelete();", true);
```

or you can also use onclientclick as well

Comment: I tried this in gridview rowdeleting event, but it asks the question. But even if I click cancel it deleted the row.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="gv1_RowDeleting">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderText="delete" />  
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CODE:

```
    protected void gv1_RowDeleting (object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
{

    GridView1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('Really wanna delete?');");

       // implement your delete logic

    Response.Write("<script>alert("Delete Successful");</script>");

}
```

This will Call Javascript function when we will click on "Delete" Command Field in Gridview  and Response.write function will give an alert that data has been deleted. You can add whwtever function you want to execute in this function.